# Is there any Python command argument which returns runtime of a code (without using time.time())?

Tags: python, windows

Is there any way to configure the python command which will return the runtime of a code? E.g., `py - <some argument> test.py` will return `test.py took 37 nanoseconds to run`? I am on Windows11 using Python 3.10.

P.S. > I want to avoid `time.time()` unless that's the only solution.

Thanks in advance.

** Solution**
Basis the comments, I tried `measure-command {py test.py}` in the command prompt. I did the job.

Thank you all.

Comment: You’d usually use other tools that call your program and tell you how long it took afterwards, no need to include this into Python itself.

Comment: @deceze : can you please suggest a way, may be, some windows cmd/PS functionality? Should I include a "Windows" or "Command Prompt" tag to my question? Thanks

Comment: Googling "powershell time command" instantly turns up ways to do that.

Comment: @user2357112: using `measure-command {py test.py}` in the command prompt did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `cProfile` for this:

```
python -m cProfile test.py
```

But it is generally better to use an external program for this, since profilers like `cProfile` have significant overhead.

Which external program to use depends on the operating system.

- ms-windows: `measure-command`
- POSIX operating systems: `time`

However, if you need to improve the speed of a Python program, `cProfile` is the tool of choice. It provides detailed insight in where your program is spending its time.

For testing small snippets of code, `timeit` is useful:

```
python3 -m timeit '"-".join(str(n) for n in range(100))'
20000 loops, best of 5: 18.4 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Basis the comments, I tried `measure-command {py test.py}` in the Windows PowerShell command prompt. It did the job.

Output:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 2
Milliseconds      : 891
Ticks             : 28910749
TotalDays         : 3.34615150462963E-05
TotalHours        : 0.000803076361111111
TotalMinutes      : 0.0481845816666667
TotalSeconds      : 2.8910749
TotalMilliseconds : 2891.0749
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `cProfile` is something that suits your needs? You can the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html.
You can add this at the beginning of a main function for instance and it returns the runtime for each function. Also the cumulative times.

You can even combine this with a package like `snakeviz` (https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/) to create a nice graph. That will show you immediately what are the bottlenecks of you program.

Comment: I want to avoid anything being captured (and returned) from the code itself. I found many such solutions including the `time` module of python.

Comment: I checked the snakeviz. Quite cool and useful. It also does what I need.